# Automatically returns _id on find()

Tags: mongoose-schema

When the schema does not include the _id field, Mongoose.find() returns the _id field automatically when the _id field is an objectId, but not returns the _id field if it is a user defined id. May I know why?

Moreover, when using the lean mode, i.e., Mongoose.find().lean(), the system always returns the _id field even the schema does not include the _id field and it is a user defined _id field. May I know why?

I did a test with three collections with the same schema. The data is added to MongoDB via mongosh.

Here is the schema

```
var dschema = new dataset.Schema({
  name: String,
  alias: String
});
```

This call accesses the collection with user defined id.

```
curl http://localhost:3000/hasid
[{"name":"Bobby","alias":"BB"},{"name":"Jimmy","alias":"JJ"}]
```

This call accesses the collection with system generated id.

```
curl http://localhost:3000/noid 
[{"_id":"656423ec75a33db175d347aa","name":"Henry","alias":"HH"},{"_id":"656423ec75a33db175d347ab","name":"Susan","alias":"SS"}]
```

This call accesses the collection with one document with user defined id and one with system generated id.

```
curl http://localhost:3000/mixed
[{"_id":"6564248375a33db175d347ac","name":"Curry","alias":"CC"},{"name":"Peter","alias":"PP"}]
```

This call accesses the same mixed set with lean mode

```
curl http://localhost:3000/lean 
[{"_id":"6564248375a33db175d347ac","name":"Curry","alias":"CC"},{"_id":95175382,"name":"Peter","alias":"PP"}]
```